# Meaning of "constant factor of N"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

In a text I am reading (Algorithms 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne) there is the [following passage](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=idUdqdDXqnAC&pg=PA262#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Increment sequences have been devised [for shellsort] that drive the asymptotic growth of the worst-case number of compares down to N^4/3, N^5/4, N^6/5, ... , but many of these results are primarily of academic interest because these functions are hard to distinguish from one another (**and from a constant factor of N** ) for practical values of N.

In this context what is the meaning of "constant factor of N"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence `N^4/3, N^5/4, N^6/5, ...` approaches `N` because the exponent gets closer and closer to `1`.

This means that the terms in "the asymptotic growth of the worst-case number of compares" get closer and closer to each other as `N` is approached. In practice, `N` can be treated as the constant factor.

(The author adds the caveat "for practical values of `N`" as, for huge values, the terms in the sequence will be distinguishable for longer.)

Answer (score 1):

It would mean that the algorithm would take N time or N operations.

Author probably wanted to emphasized difference between N and O(N) time complexity in this case.